# MouseDragScrolling in Java

Tags: java, click, scroll, mouse, drag

I want to build a MouseDragScrolling like Android over Java for a big touch screen something like this http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/scrollable-timelines.html I have this example http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.mx/2008/06/mouse-drag-auto-scrolling.html but i want to use the MouseDragScrolling over a JTable or other component and block and distinct the MouseClick and the MouseDrag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to automate user actions, Look at [FEST](http://fest.easytesting.org/). It will solve your problem, if you are working on a Swing application.